# Server application get bad ipHostInfo.AddressList[0]

Tags: c#, server, tcp

I have server application [image: Image of application server left, same host as client at right].

If I run it at server application just do not communicate with client. I try allow all ports used ports in firewall also whole application, but it did not helped. At localhost it works fine. Working system is correctly updated Win 10. Server is windows server 2012.

```
public void Listen(object data)
    {
  // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
    // The DNS name of the computer  
    // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".  
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
    // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
    Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...at" + localEndPoint.ToString());
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Those are IPv6 Adresses. Did you check both IPv4 and IPv6 Firewall settings? Did you intend to use IPv6? Also, in the left Picture, it is listening on "::1" ...

Comment: Looks like server has no IPv6 adress... how to make it use IPv4 ?

Comment: Ahhh, lemme look that up, quickly. It's been ages since I've done that by hand.

Comment: IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0]; At first position there is IPv6 adress
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1]; At Second position there is IPv4 adress

Server comunicated write resolution that i can give you resolution :)

Comment: Fildor thanks you very mutch ! :) You guided me right way!

Comment: If you're not trying to bind to a *specific* address, you could just use `IPAddress.Any` in creating your endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you should be using IPv4 Adresses.

You can use IPAdress's [AdressFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily?view=net-5.0) property to get a to valid IPv4 Address ("InterNetwork"). Also check [`isLoopback()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.isloopback?view=net-5.0).

So, basically

```
IPAdress myIp = ipHostInfo
                  .AddressList
                  .Where( a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => !IPAdress.IsLoopback(x));
```

should give you a good one if one exists.

... **or** as Damien_The_Unbeliever so greatly reminded me in comment:
Just use `IPAdress.Any` to listen on *any* ip.